# Async method to update ui executes partially

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, async-await, task

I'm developing an android app using xamarin and what I'm trying to do is really simple: on the click of a button disable itself for 1 second.

Here's the relevant part of the code I put together:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
//...
        sendShortDataButton.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
                Task.Run(() => DisableButtonFor());               
            };
//...
        private async Task DisableButtonFor()
        {
            sendShortDataButton.Enabled = false; //<------
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            sendShortDataButton.Enabled = true;
        }
}
```

The problem here is that, by debugging the app, the code runs only to where the arrow points everything after gets ignored. On the app the button does actually get disabled, so I'm not really sure what's going wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
sendShortDataButton.Click += async (sender, e) =>
{
    var button = (Button)sender;
    button.Enabled = false;
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    button.Enabled = true;
};
```

You don't need `Task.Run` if the only async work you have is to await a `Task.Delay`. But if you do have more async work to do, then it's better to use `Task.Run` for this work only:

```
sendShortDataButton.Click += async (sender, e) =>
{
    var button = (Button)sender;
    button.Enabled = false;
    await Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000); // Simulate async work
    });
    button.Enabled = true;
};
```

Comment: Thank you, this solution worked perfectly! Trying to understand what I did wrong, would it be something along these lines?:  it was not necessary to run the async method on a backgroud thread, and that was preventing the button state to be set again.

Comment: I don't know much about Xamarin, but in general bad things are happening when the controls of a UI application are accessed from any thread other than the UI thread. About the behavior of the Visual Studio during debugging I also know very little, because personally I prefer to test my apps with Ctrl+F5 (without debugging).